# Assigning int to struct array but prints out as 0 (different)

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I Am sorry for the bad title so my code is this:

```
struct Point{
    double X,Y;
};

int main() {
    int i,j;
    struct Point arr[5];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        arr[i].X=11;
        arr[i].Y=22;
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d- X = %d -- Y = %d\n",i+1,arr[i].X,arr[i].Y);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

and as output i get

```
1- X = 0 -- Y = 0
2- X = 0 -- Y = 0
3- X = 0 -- Y = 0
4- X = 0 -- Y = 0
5- X = 0 -- Y = 0
```

But when i look into VSC debug section i see that my arr[0] has X and Y values and they are the correct values. So i am assuming there's printing issue but couldn't figure out why.

Also i could be missing very big deal about struct array and assiging int to them but please let me know!
Thanks.

EDIT: My apologies on vsc debug screen it was showing up without double number so i thought it would be okay to use %d.. My bad Thanks!

Comment: Try reading the documentation for `printf`. What does it say is expected for a `%d` placeholder in the string? What does it say should be the placeholder for a `double`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking *undefined behavior* by passind data having wrong type to `printf()`. `%d` expects `int`, but you are passing `double`. You should use format specifier `%f`, `%g`, `%e`, or `%a` to print `double`.

Format specifyer `%.0f` or `%g` should be used to print without printing dots in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Totally my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct members have type `double`, but you're using the `%d` format specifier to print them which expects an `int`.

You instead want `%f`:

```
printf("%d- X = %f -- Y = %f\n",i+1,arr[i].X,arr[i].Y);
```

Comment: The members don't have type `float`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Totally my bad.